# "Inset" and maybe "snap" to edge or something else than "snap"?

Tags: modeling

My question is about inset and probably snap.

I would like to inset the face of a cylinder to the size of the face of another cylinder which is behind. I thought it will work by snapping but inset-tool is not snapping at all. Is the snap-tool the right way or is there another option to do so?

I have read the Blender documentation about the inset-tool, searched the internet and forum here for my question without success.

The red arrow is showing the face of the cylinder behind and I want this size of my inset:

[image: Red arrow shows targeted face size of inset]

Here is my project to see what I need it for or why I ask this question:

[image]

(Green shows the cylinder behind and red the size of the inset which I would like to get)

Comment: Hi. Couldn't you just inset the face 1/2 the amount of the difference between the diameters of the two objects?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but it won't really help me. I thought it would be easy to give an example, but it looks like it just leads in the wrong direction. I'm sorry for that. I'll send another screenshot to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, Snap is the way to go. Enable Scale in the Snap settings.

Comment: I still think curious_1's method applies. The way I would do it is first scale so the radius or diamater is 1 (e.g. if the diameter is $1.3$, then you hit S/1.3 keys), then I scale to get the radius/diameter I want. If precision is important, scale by any amount, hit F9 key and paste an exact value.

Comment: Thanks to all of you: I don't think I fully understood your answers - maybe it's just because I'm quite a beginner when it comes to Blender. But your answers still inspired me to find the following solution: I duplicated the target face of my cylinder, checked the diameter of the cylinder behind it and scaled it precisely by entering values directly into the dimensions. Then I used the Inset-Tool and scaled the result exactly like the duplicated face - voilà.

Comment: "curios_1" and "Markus von Broady":
Did you even want to tell me something like that or have I completely misunderstood both of you?


"MarkusvonBroady":
The “F9-Key” gave me no option to enter values at all. Have I probably accidentally changed the keyboard layout or is there something else wrong/should I pay attention to something else?

Comment: @RumenBelev Snapping instead of scaling would of course also be possible - thank you very much for this advice.